# Нестандартная инициализация for

Tags: c++, for

Когда изучал строки и векторы, наткнулся на вывод вектора таким образом

```
for(auto str : dictionary)
    std::cout << str << "\n";
```

или

```
for(std::string n : clangs)
    std::cout << n << "\t";
```

Как это работает?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это пошло с нового стандарта `C++11`. Называется Range-For.

Перебираются все элементы контейнера, указанного справа от двоеточия.

Хорошие практики - использовать ссылки (чтобы не происходило копирование), `auto` (чтобы не загромождать декларации), и `const` (чтобы не стрелять себе по ногам).

Если не нужно изменять значения элементов:

```
for(const auto& i:data)
{
}
```

Если нужно изменять:

```
for(auto& i:data)
{
}
```